# Инициализирование класса внутри другого класса и использование методов другого класса

Tags: python, ооп

В методе extract_data класса Urisbed, я хочу использовать метод increase_numbers класса Besdection  но получаю ошибку AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'increase_numbers'.
Это случается из-за того, что Urisbed не сабкласс Besdection или же есть другая ошибка в коде?

```
from typing import Dict, Tuple, List, Set, Optional, TextIO
from datetime import date

class Besdection:
    """
    === примеры ===
    >>> b = Besdection(date(2020, 12, 20))
    >>> b._d
    datetime.date(2020, 12, 20)
    >>> b._places
    ['Moscow', 'Perm', 'Kiev']
    >>> b._parties
    ['Edrs', 'Best', 'Fade']
    >>> b._numbers
    {'Moscow': {'Edrs': 3, 'Best': 12, 'Fade': 30},
     'Perm': {'Edrs': 4, 'Best': 2, 'Fade': 10},
     'Kiev': {'Edrs': 7, 'Best': 8, 'Fade': 1}
    """
    _d: date
    _places: List[str]
    _darcys: List[str]
    _numbers: Dict[str, Dict[str, int]]

    def __init__(self, d: date) -> None:
        """Initialize a new besdection on date d and with no place, darcy,
        or numbers.

        >>> b = Besdection(date(2020, 12, 20))
        >>> b._d
        datetime.date(2020, 12, 20)
        """
        self._d = d
        self._places = []
        self._darcys = []
        self._numbers = {}

    def increase_numbers(self, place: str, darcy: str, numbers: int) -> None:
        """
        Условие: numbers >= 1

        >>> B = Besdection(date(2000, 2, 8))
        >>> b.increase_numbers('Moscow', 'Edrs', 12)
        >>> b._darcys
        {'Moscow':{'Edrs':12}
        >>> b.increase_numbers('Moscow', 'Best', 14)
        >>> b._darcys
        {'Moscow':{'Edrs':12, 'Best': 14}}
        """
        self._darcys.append(place)
        if place not in self._numbers:
            self._numbers[place] = {darcy:numbers}
        elif place in self._numbers:
            if darcy not in self._numbers[place]:
                self._numbers[place][darcy] = numbers
            elif darcy in self._numbers[place]:
                self._numbers[place][darcy] += numbers


class Urisbed:
    _name: str
    _besdections: Dict[date, Besdection]

    def __init__(self, name: str) -> None:
        """
        >>> country = Urisbed('Russia')
        >>> country._name
        'Russia'
        >>> country._bestedctions
        {}
        """
        self._name = name
        self._besdections = {}

    def extract_data(self, year: int, month: int, day: int,
                     input_file: TextIO) -> None:
        """
        Условие: input_file уже открыт.
        """
        b = Besdection.__init__(self, date(year, month, day))
        input_file.readline()
        for line in input_file:
            columns = line.split(',')
            place = columns[1].strip('"')
            darcy = columns[13].strip('"')
            number = int(columns[17])
            if number > 0:
                b.update_results(self, place, darcy, number)
        self._besdections[date(year, month, day)] = b
```

Comment: попробуйте заменить `b = Besdection.__init__(self, date(year, month, day))` на `b = Besdection(date(year, month, day))`

Comment: спасибо помогло